# How do I search footnotes in a Pages Document?

Tags: pages, iwork

When I try to search for an existing footnote's number no results come back. Is there some special setting to search for footnotes?

Answer (score 1):

I have an older version of Pages, which I normally do not use as I use LibreOffice, however I just created a document in Pages, added a Footnote and then clicked **Edit** > **Find** > **Search** and typed in a *number*.  It found all occurrences of that *number* which included both *numbers* in the document body and in the Footnotes.  I could easily tell which was the Footnote vs a *number* in the body of the text as the *number* was the first character in a given line after the ellipsis.  Not as nice as having a **Go to Footnote [`n`]** *command* but I still found the Footnote.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't work for me on a newer version of Pages. Perhaps it could be the document I'm using was imported from a word doc and that is causing the issue.

Comment: @Steve Moser, Does it work on a document that was originally created in Pages, in the newer version?